# how to deserialize and get member value using boost library

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, deserialization

First of all, I would like to tell that

1. I am new in serialization technique
2. I am not completely blank of using boost serialization but most of the example I have gone through are quite direct(eg. only one class, maximum one base and one derived class).

I have taken the example from [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/serialization/example/demo.cpp). Here, the writer of the code has used `save` and `load` function by using the class `bus_schedule`. I am getting problem of fetching all member variable with the help of the object called here `new_schedule`. I am assuming that, this object will help me to fetch all the member of the other class(maybe I am totally wrong in this point).

Apart from this, I have seen that, most of the member variable are here `private` that means I cannot access them from `main` function. That's why, I have set some getter function to return some member value. For example, from `bus_schedule` class if I can return `schedule` list then I can access `trip_info` struct value as well as the pointer which type is `bus_route`.

The function to return `schedule` list I have  used is:

```
std::list<std::pair<trip_info, bus_route *> >  return_schedule()
     {
         return schedule;
     }
```

And in the `main` function I have used:

```
bus_schedule new_schedule;
auto returning_schedule = new_schedule.return_schedule();
for(auto i:returning_schedule)
    {
        cout<<(i.first)<<" ~~~~~~~ "<<(i.second)<<endl;
       /*with i.first I can access the struct info, i.second pointer gives me the info of
       bus_route pointer value ater dereferencing*/
    }
```

But here again I have stucked to get the seperate value from the i.second pointer. I know here, `bus_route` class has a list named `stops`. [Here](https://gist.github.com/atifkarim/6f59a1073ca272e1128d1cb7f85215ef#file-demo-cpp-L215) also returned this. But this seems to me messy every time to do this back-calculation.

My question is, is there any direct soltution from `boost` to acess all member variable after deserialization? I will set getter function for all class but afraid of finding pathway to use those.

Answer (score 1):

This question is actually separate from serialization. Here's distilled to the datastructure without serialization stuff. I modernized the code to use C++17 features

- `auto` and move semantics
- `default`ed special members
- `[[nodiscard]]`, `override` keyword for virtuals
- explicit constructors and `emplace`
- ranged-for loop with destructuring
- `make_unique<>` instead of `new`/`delete`
- extended aggregate initializers

All in all it makes the code shorter, simpler and more efficient¹. Also, it hightlights some of the things you wanted to know, which I'll show below.

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb551a31f25a2372)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

struct gps_position {
    int degrees;
    int minutes;
    float seconds;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const gps_position& gp) {
        return os << ' ' << gp.degrees << "º" << gp.minutes << "'" << gp.seconds << '"';
    }
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// One bus stop
struct bus_stop {
    gps_position latitude, longitude;

    [[nodiscard]] virtual std::string description() const = 0;
    virtual ~bus_stop() = default;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const bus_stop& bs) {
        return os << bs.latitude << bs.longitude << ' ' << bs.description();
    }

  protected:
    explicit bus_stop(gps_position _lat, gps_position _long)
            : latitude(_lat), longitude(_long) {}
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Several kinds of bus stops
struct bus_stop_corner : bus_stop {
    std::string street1, street2;
    [[nodiscard]] std::string description() const override {
        return street1 + " and " + street2;
    }

    explicit bus_stop_corner(gps_position _lat, gps_position _long, std::string _s1, std::string _s2)
        : bus_stop(_lat, _long), street1(std::move(_s1)), street2(std::move(_s2)) {}
};

struct bus_stop_destination : bus_stop {
    std::string name;
    [[nodiscard]] std::string description() const override { return name; }

    bus_stop_destination(gps_position _lat, gps_position _long, std::string _name)
        : bus_stop(_lat, _long), name(std::move(_name)) {}
};

struct bus_route {
    using bus_stop_pointer = bus_stop*;
    std::list<bus_stop_pointer> stops;

    void append(bus_stop* _bs) { stops.insert(stops.end(), _bs); }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const bus_route& br) {
        for (auto& stop : br.stops) {
            os << '\n' << std::hex << "0x" << stop << std::dec << ' ' << *stop;
        }
        return os;
    }
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// a bus schedule is a collection of routes each with a starting time
struct bus_schedule {
    struct trip_info { int hour, minute; std::string driver; };

    void append(const std::string& _d, int _h, int _m, bus_route* _br) {
        schedule.emplace(schedule.end(), trip_info{_h, _m, _d}, _br);
    }

  private:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const bus_schedule& bs) {
        for (auto const& [k,v] : bs.schedule) { os << k << *v; }
        return os;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const bus_schedule::trip_info& ti) {
        return os << '\n' << ti.hour << ':' << ti.minute << ' ' << ti.driver << ' ';
    }
    std::list<std::pair<trip_info, bus_route*>> schedule;
};

int main() {
    // fill in the data
    // make a few stops
    auto bs0 = std::make_unique<bus_stop_corner>(
        gps_position{ 34, 135, 52.560F }, gps_position{ 134, 22, 78.30F },
        "24th Street", "10th Avenue");
    auto bs1 = std::make_unique<bus_stop_corner>(
        gps_position{ 35, 137, 23.456F }, gps_position{ 133, 35, 54.12F },
        "State street", "Cathedral Vista Lane");
    auto bs2 = std::make_unique<bus_stop_destination>(
        gps_position{ 35, 136, 15.456F }, gps_position{ 133, 32, 15.300F },
        "White House");
    auto bs3 = std::make_unique<bus_stop_destination>(
        gps_position{ 35, 134, 48.789F }, gps_position{ 133, 32, 16.230F },
        "Lincoln Memorial");

    // make the schedule
    bus_schedule original_schedule;
    bus_route route0;

    bus_route route1;

    {
        // make a route
        route0.append(bs0.get());
        route0.append(bs1.get());
        route0.append(bs2.get());

        // add trips to schedule
        original_schedule.append("bob",   6,  24, &route0);
        original_schedule.append("bob",   9,  57, &route0);
        original_schedule.append("alice", 11, 2,  &route0);
    }

    {
        // make aother routes
        route1.append(bs3.get());
        route1.append(bs2.get());
        route1.append(bs1.get());

        // add trips to schedule
        original_schedule.append("ted",   7,  17, &route1);
        original_schedule.append("ted",   9,  38, &route1);
        original_schedule.append("alice", 11, 47, &route1);
    }

    // display the complete schedule
    std::cout << "schedule" << original_schedule;
}
```

Prints:

```
schedule
6:24 bob 
 34º135'52.56" 134º22'78.3" 24th Street and 10th Avenue
 35º137'23.456" 133º35'54.12" State street and Cathedral Vista Lane
 35º136'15.456" 133º32'15.3" White House
9:57 bob 
 34º135'52.56" 134º22'78.3" 24th Street and 10th Avenue
 35º137'23.456" 133º35'54.12" State street and Cathedral Vista Lane
 35º136'15.456" 133º32'15.3" White House
11:2 alice 
 34º135'52.56" 134º22'78.3" 24th Street and 10th Avenue
 35º137'23.456" 133º35'54.12" State street and Cathedral Vista Lane
 35º136'15.456" 133º32'15.3" White House
7:17 ted 
 35º134'48.789" 133º32'16.23" Lincoln Memorial
 35º136'15.456" 133º32'15.3" White House
 35º137'23.456" 133º35'54.12" State street and Cathedral Vista Lane
9:38 ted 
 35º134'48.789" 133º32'16.23" Lincoln Memorial
 35º136'15.456" 133º32'15.3" White House
 35º137'23.456" 133º35'54.12" State street and Cathedral Vista Lane
11:47 alice 
 35º134'48.789" 133º32'16.23" Lincoln Memorial
 35º136'15.456" 133º32'15.3" White House
 35º137'23.456" 133º35'54.12" State street and Cathedral Vista Lane
```

### Conclusion

To conveniently use that `map` datastructure, you can use the loop [as the example has it](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/serialization/example/demo.cpp):

```
std::list<
    std::pair<bus_schedule::trip_info, bus_route*>>::const_iterator it;
for (it = bs.schedule.begin(); it != bs.schedule.end(); it++) {
    os << it->first << *(it->second);
}
```

However, in C++17 you'd write exactly the same as:

```
for (auto const& [info,route] : bs.schedule) { os << info << *route; }
```

You can see that `[k, v]` uses structured bindings to extract the "first" and "second" parts of the value-type. If you don't have C++17 features in your compiler, you can always manually do the same:

```
for (auto const& pair : bs.schedule) {
    trip_info const& info = pair.first;
    bus_route const& route = *pair.second;
    os << info << route;
}
```

### Getting Around `private` members

I'd submit that this datastructure is not typical or "good" idiomatic C++. The use of raw pointers invites memory management errors (e.g. every stop from the deserialized routes is leaked).

Adding onto this "contraption" getters/setters risks [putting lipstick on a pig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipstick_on_a_pig#:%7E:text=To%20put%20%22lipstick%20on%20a,to%20disguise%20its%20fundamental%20failings.)².

I would instead elect to make public what you need public. Here's a sample that does the printing of details all from main, without overloading the `operator<<` operators:

```
// display the complete schedule
std::cout << "schedule";
for (auto const& [info,route] : original_schedule.schedule) {
    std::cout << '\n' << info.hour << ':' << info.minute << ' ' << info.driver << ' ';
    for (auto& stop : route->stops)
        std::cout << '\n' << stop->latitude << stop->longitude << ' ' << stop->description();
}
```

Prints the same as before.

### Full Listing

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8461763afac34858)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

struct gps_position {
    int degrees;
    int minutes;
    float seconds;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const gps_position& gp) {
        return os << ' ' << gp.degrees << "º" << gp.minutes << "'" << gp.seconds << '"';
    }
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// One bus stop
struct bus_stop {
    gps_position latitude, longitude;

    [[nodiscard]] virtual std::string description() const = 0;
    virtual ~bus_stop() = default;

    explicit bus_stop(gps_position _lat, gps_position _long)
            : latitude(_lat), longitude(_long) {}
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Several kinds of bus stops
struct bus_stop_corner : bus_stop {
    std::string street1, street2;
    [[nodiscard]] std::string description() const override {
        return street1 + " and " + street2;
    }

    explicit bus_stop_corner(gps_position _lat, gps_position _long, std::string _s1, std::string _s2)
        : bus_stop(_lat, _long), street1(std::move(_s1)), street2(std::move(_s2)) {}
};

struct bus_stop_destination : bus_stop {
    std::string name;
    [[nodiscard]] std::string description() const override { return name; }

    bus_stop_destination(gps_position _lat, gps_position _long, std::string _name)
        : bus_stop(_lat, _long), name(std::move(_name)) {}
};

struct bus_route {
    std::list<bus_stop*> stops;
    void append(bus_stop* _bs) { stops.push_back(_bs); }
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// a bus schedule is a collection of routes each with a starting time
struct bus_schedule {
    struct trip_info { int hour, minute; std::string driver; };

    void append(const std::string& _d, int _h, int _m, bus_route* _br) {
        schedule.emplace(schedule.end(), trip_info{_h, _m, _d}, _br);
    }

    std::list<std::pair<trip_info, bus_route*>> schedule;
};

int main() {
    // fill in the data
    // make a few stops
    auto bs0 = std::make_unique<bus_stop_corner>(
        gps_position{ 34, 135, 52.560F }, gps_position{ 134, 22, 78.30F },
        "24th Street", "10th Avenue");
    auto bs1 = std::make_unique<bus_stop_corner>(
        gps_position{ 35, 137, 23.456F }, gps_position{ 133, 35, 54.12F },
        "State street", "Cathedral Vista Lane");
    auto bs2 = std::make_unique<bus_stop_destination>(
        gps_position{ 35, 136, 15.456F }, gps_position{ 133, 32, 15.300F },
        "White House");
    auto bs3 = std::make_unique<bus_stop_destination>(
        gps_position{ 35, 134, 48.789F }, gps_position{ 133, 32, 16.230F },
        "Lincoln Memorial");

    // make the schedule
    bus_schedule original_schedule;
    bus_route route0;

    bus_route route1;

    {
        // make a route
        route0.append(bs0.get());
        route0.append(bs1.get());
        route0.append(bs2.get());

        // add trips to schedule
        original_schedule.append("bob",   6,  24, &route0);
        original_schedule.append("bob",   9,  57, &route0);
        original_schedule.append("alice", 11, 2,  &route0);
    }

    {
        // make aother routes
        route1.append(bs3.get());
        route1.append(bs2.get());
        route1.append(bs1.get());

        // add trips to schedule
        original_schedule.append("ted",   7,  17, &route1);
        original_schedule.append("ted",   9,  38, &route1);
        original_schedule.append("alice", 11, 47, &route1);
    }

    // display the complete schedule
    std::cout << "schedule";
    for (auto const& [info,route] : original_schedule.schedule) {
        std::cout << '\n' << info.hour << ':' << info.minute << ' ' << info.driver << ' ';
        for (auto& stop : route->stops)
            std::cout << '\n' << stop->latitude << stop->longitude << ' ' << stop->description();
    }
}
```

> Note how the code is 100 lines of code shorter than the sample even when [removing all blank lines and comments, and using the same formatting](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a6a20803a9dad50).

---

¹ note that the code is clearly not objectively "efficient" at all since it does all manner of dynamic allocation and runtime polymorphism

² This anti-pattern is common for people with a background in traditional OOP, see [pseudo/quasi-classes](https://www.idinews.com/quasiClass.pdf) (PDF)

Comment: For completeness, [here's the final listing **Live On Coliru** INCLUDING serialization code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6851e1ea3abe9bce): I added the minimum number of accessors (`get_schedule()` and `get_stops()`). Note that this gives you the memory leaks back as I described in my answer.